# Javascript regex to count occurrences of hashtags in a textarea

Tags: javascript, html, regex, data-binding

I am trying to add a count value before each hashtag in a textarea like this:

```
"An example #string containing a #few #hashtags"
"An example 1:#string containing a 2:#few 3:#hashtags"
```

I need the counters to appear in real time as the user is typing.

I am using a `keyup()` event callback to check the value of the textarea and trying to insert the count before each occurrence of a hashtag using a regex match:

```js
let value = '';
let _textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
_textarea.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  value = _textarea.value;
  let tags = value.match(/(#\S*)/g); //Match all hashtags
  
  
  let i = 0;
  value = value.replace(/(#\S*)/g, matched => {
   console.log(matched, i);
    i++;
    return i + ':' + matched;
  });
  
  
  _textarea.value = value;
  console.log(tags);
});
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

The problem is that this continuously prepends the counter after each keyup event is triggered.

What would be a suitable solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improving on [@Cameron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2037347/cameron)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47040842/3600709), this one allows for a hashtag to be used at the start of a string as well.

```js
let _textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
_textarea.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  let target = e.target;
  let value = target.value;
  
  let i = 0;
  value = value.replace(/.?#/g, matched => {
    i++;
    let output = matched;
    if (/(?:[^:]|^)#/.test(matched)) {
      if(matched.length > 1) {
        output = `${matched[0]}${i}:${matched[1]}`;
      } else {
        output = `${i}:${matched[0]}`;
      }
    }
    return output;
  });
  
  _textarea.value = value;
});
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let _textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
_textarea.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  let target = e.target;
  let value = target.value;
  
  let i = 0;
  value = value.replace(/.?#/g, matched => {
    i++;
    let output = matched;
    if (/[^:]#/.test(matched)) {
      output = `${matched[0]}${i}:${matched[1]}`;
    }
    return output;
  });
  
  _textarea.value = value;
});
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

I have made some changes to your code that I believe achieve what you want.

Inside your replace function I have added a conditional that only attaches the index to the hashtag if it doesn't have a colon in front of it already

Answer (score 0):

In `value.replace` use `/.#/g`. This regex will return hashtag with it's previous symbol. So you can check if it ":" or not

```
value = value.replace(/.#/g, matched => {
   i++;
   if(matched[0] === ':')
      return matched;
   return i + ':' + matched;
});
```

Comment: Will this leave the correct indexing of the hashtags though? I think this will leave all hashtags marked as 1

Comment: Edited my answer